# how to create html tables defining a columns at a time

Tags: php, html

I have two for loops to draw a HTML table and I want to draw the columns from the first for loop and add the rows from the second for loop. But the tables cant draw in the following way.

```
for($i=0;$i<$diffc;$i++){
                    ?>

                    <td>
                    <?php
                    for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){
                        ?>
                <tr>MODEL</tr>
                        <tr><?php echo $modelNo; ?></tr>    
                        <tr>MODELw</tr>
                        <tr><?php echo $model; ?></tr>

                        <?php
                    }
                    ?>

                    </td>
                    <?php

            }
```

Any idea how I should do this?

Comment: 1) I don't see any loop; 2) You switched `tr`s with `td`s

Comment: for($i=0;$i<$diffc;$i++){
     ?>
    
              <td>
      <?php
     for($j=0;$j<2;$j++){
      ?>
      <tr>MODEL</tr>
                        <tr><?php echo $modelNo; ?></tr> 
                        <tr>MODELw</tr>
                        <tr><?php echo $model; ?></tr>
                      
                        <?php
     }
     ?>
    
              </td>
      <?php
      
   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right, tables are drawn *row* first, then by *column* (can't be the other way around).

So, you might want to (assuming you're using PHP):

1. Create your 2-dimensional array representing the table cell values (in PHP).
2. Draw your table by iterating through each row, then by column.

You do end up having to perform extra loops with this method.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to undrestand how tables work in html then you can do it easily in php.

So you are using two loops to draw the table. In the first loop you want to draw the columns and in the second you want to draw the rows. So here is how to do it.

here is structure of html table.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td>1 Column</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

In the first loop draw the following html code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Column 1</td><td>Column 2</td><td>Column 3</td>
</tr>
```

end of first loop.

then in the second loop draw the following html

```
<tr>
<td>row 1</td><td>row 2</td><td>row 3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>row 1</td><td>row 2</td><td>row 3</td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>row 1</td><td>row 2</td><td>row 3</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

If you dont know how to do it in php then let me know.